# How to save data offline using coredata, and if network comes(online) send the saved data to the API?

Tags: ios, swift, api, offline, reachability

How to save data in offline using *coredata*, and if network comes(online) send the saved data to the API?

This is the code to save data:

```
func savePSaveInfo(cId: String, pId:String, createdBy:String, agep:String, languageId:String, emailId:String, mobileNumber:String,backendUpdate: Bool)
{    
    let nameObj = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "SaveInfo", into: context!) as! SaveInfo

    nameObj.cId = cId
    nameObj.pId = pId
    nameObj.createdBy = createdBy
    nameObj.agep = agep
    nameObj.languageId = languageId
    nameObj.emailId = emailId
    nameObj.mobileNumber = mobileNumber
    nameObj.backendUpdate = backendUpdate    

    do{
        try context!.save()
    }catch{
        print("not saved")
    }
}
```

Comment: please share what you did to do this. Basically you should create a service like `ConnectivityService` to check the internet connection and if it is offline you should save data via `CoreData` then you can observe notification from your `ConnectivityService`. When network comes online you can send data from `CoreData` to API

Comment: please consider this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide reproducable copyable code, because this is not a "we write code for you for free"-platform but a "we help you with your provided code "-platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For inserting value in core data, I am sharing a example , you can set according to you data.

Step 1 :- Set the entity like this [image]

Step 2:-

```
//MARK:- FOR CREATING NEW DATA
    func createData(){

        //As we know that container is set up in the AppDelegates so we need to refer that container.
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }

        //We need to create a context from this container
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        //Now let’s create an entity and new user records.
        let userEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: managedContext)!

        //final, we need to add some data to our newly created record for each keys using


        let user = NSManagedObject(entity: userEntity, insertInto: managedContext)
        user.setValue(txtFldUsername.text!, forKeyPath: "username")
        user.setValue(txtFldEmail.text!, forKey: "email")
        user.setValue(txtFldPassword.text!, forKey: "password")

        retrieveData()
        //Now we have set all the values. The next step is to save them inside the Core Data

        do {
            try managedContext.save()

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

Stop 3:- For fetching data

```
 //MARK:- FOR RETRIEVING OR FETCHING THE DATA
    func retrieveData() {

        //As we know that container is set up in the AppDelegates so we need to refer that container.
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }

        //We need to create a context from this container
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        //Prepare the request of type NSFetchRequest  for the entity
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "User")

        do {
            let result = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            arrUserDetails.removeAll()
            for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
                print(data.value(forKey: "username") as! String)
                arrUserDetails.append(userData(username: (data.value(forKey: "username") as! String), email: (data.value(forKey: "email") as! String), password: (data.value(forKey: "password") as! String)))
            }
            tblView.reloadData()

        } catch {

            print("Failed")
        }
    }
```

Still there is any issue , let me know about the query